# How to remove java method pararmeters when certain condition is met

Tags: java, function, methods, parameters, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find a way to remove a method parameter when a certain condition is met. If the condition is met - then the parameter should be taken away from the method - but if the condition is not met - the parameter should be added back again to that method. Is there any way to do this in java - I know overloaded methods can do this - but how can a method remove its parameters and add them back again is my question.

```java
if(condition == true) {
     //remove the parameter from the method because it is not needed
} else {
    //add the parameter back again to the method so the code below can use it
}

/*
code which uses the parameter again...
*/
```

Thank you so much for helping - hope this was not too confusing

Comment: Why do you want to _remove the parameter_ from the method, instead of just _not use the parameter_? Is it causing a problem just by existing and not being used sometimes?

Comment: you can not just use overloaded version of the method

Comment: it seems like, you are trying to implement method overloading, check this for method overloading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: This is not a thing you can do.  You can't add and remove parameters, only not use them.

Comment: Looks a lot like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need this? There are other ways that achieve a similar result in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't support changing method signatures during Runtime. You could instead just overload the same method, with 2 signatures like so:

```
public void method(int param1, int param2, int optional) {}

public void method(int param1, int param2) {
    method(param1, param2, 'value, that is optional, but not necessary currently');
}
```

The changing of Signatures is not possible, because it would break everything, that accesses the method using its originial signature.